# What is the meaning of compile time abstraction?

Tags: oop, compiler-construction, programming-languages, language-design, typechecking

I came across the sentence, "Compile time abstraction of runtime behaviour", what is compile time abstraction here? My guesses would be,

like in a language, trying to optimize/do things that can be done at compile time, and only leaving room for things that can be done only at the run time,

For Example.
           int a; 
           a = 5;// 5 can be assigned to a only at compile time(unless it is a const), because the user might have created the program, where he gets the input from commandline, stdin,fin etc etc

where as, int a// can be done at compile time, since you know the type right away......

Comment: What was the context?  i.e. where did you read this?

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/emeijer/Papers/RDL04Meijer.pdf

Comment: @ Anonymous downvoter, please feel free to comment, and tell me whats wrong with my question.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are confused by "compile-time abstraction" in

> Static type checking is a compile-time abstraction of the runtime behaviour of your program, ...

(quote from the paper "Static Typing Where Possible, Dynamic Typing When Needed" that you've linked to in your comment)

If the word "abstraction" was replaced by "approximation", would that make more sense to you?

Given an expression E of type T, we can say that T approximates at compile-time the sort of values computed at run-time (when evaluating E). For example, say you have an expression [2+2*3] of type [integer] -- you could say that "this expression will evaluate to an integer".